# Notification badge count managment in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, badge

I am having a notification table in the database in which I am getting notification value via the API and showing it to the angular notification panel with badge count with the help of CSS styling. I would like to reduce the notification count when the user reads the notification, how can I achieve this? I don't use WebSocket for the notification list which we have to get from the backend table as a notification source. kindly advise.

Comment: How is the count read?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `boolean` attribute in the `db` `notification` `entity` and once the `UI` changes (i.e the notification is read by users) you update the `boolean` status in your `db`.